# Content type does not match binding

Tags: web-services, content-type

I'm calling a third party java web service from C#. It was working fine until they changed the server's message encoding from `Mtom` to Text. I changed the binding in the config file and now whenever I call the service I'm getting this error:

> The content type multipart/related;
>   type="text/xml"; of the response
>   message does not match the content
>   type of the binding (text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8).

If you look at the response it contains this:

> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

I can't see why it is complaining about the binding when the content-type is exactly the same. Does anyone have any ideas? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Maybe along with the encoding something else changed. Have you tried regenerating your proxy from the WSDL?

Comment: I requested to get an updated WSDL but haven't heard back if this is applicable.

Comment: When you changed from MTOM to text-only, did you change the response _mechanism_ from multi-part (MIME) to a straight-up HTTP response? If you're not sure, maybe try something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to take a look at the raw conversation.